# Прошу помощи с обобщённые типами (generics)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, typescript

Не буду здесь приводить тонны своего кода, покажу на примере в чём проблема.

---

Есть какой-то класс (пусть будет `Foo`) с методом `generateJson`, который возвращает `JSON` типа `FooGenerateJsonType`:

```
@Component({})
export default class Foo {
    protected generateJson(): FooGenerateJsonType {
        return {
            data {
                test1: "TEST1"
            }
        }
    }
}

interface FooGenerateJsonType {
    data: FooGenerateJsonTypeData;
}

interface FooGenerateJsonTypeData {
    test1: string;
}
```

У `FooGenerateJsonType` есть `data` которая имеет тип `FooGenerateJsonTypeData` с набором каких-то **своих** параметров.

Есть второй класс (пусть будет `Bar`), который наследуется от `Foo`:

```
@Component({})
export default class Bar extends Foo {
    protected generateJson(): BarGenerateJsonType {
        return {
            data {
                test2: "TEST2",
                test3: "TEST3"
            }
        }
    }
}

interface BarGenerateJsonType {
    data: BarGenerateJsonTypeData;
}

interface BarGenerateJsonTypeData {
    test2: string;
    test3?: string;
}
```

Как видно, класс `Bar` **переопределяет** метод `generateJson`, но **возвращает совершенно другой тип** данных.

---

Скорее всего здесь уместно использовать [generics](https://canonium.com/articles/typescript-generics). Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это грамотно сделать в моём случае? Ошибка примерно такая:

> Property '`generateJson`' in type '`Bar`' is not assignable to the same
>   property in base type '`Foo`'. Type '`() => BarGenerateJsonType`' is not
>   assignable to type '`() => FooGenerateJsonType`'.

Comment: Пожалуйста, [не надо "разукрашивать" ответы внутристрочным форматированием](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/339133). Почему-то всем новичкам нравится, когда код просто пестрит внутристрочным, но по факту это излишне и вредно (отвлекает). Посмотрите на мете описание случаев, когда нужно использовать внутристрочное форматирование: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1328/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать что-то вроде такого.

```
class Base<T> {
  generateJson(): T {
    return;
  }
}

interface FooGenerateJsonType {
  data: FooGenerateJsonTypeData;
}

interface FooGenerateJsonTypeData {
  test1: string;
}

class Foo extends Base<FooGenerateJsonType> {
   generateJson(): FooGenerateJsonType {
    return {
      data: {
        test1: 'TEST1'
      }
    };
  }
}

class Bar extends Base<BarGenerateJsonType> {
   generateJson(): BarGenerateJsonType {
    return {
      data: {
        test2: 'TEST2',
        test3: 'TEST3'
      }
    };
  }
}

interface BarGenerateJsonType {
  data: BarGenerateJsonTypeData;
}

interface BarGenerateJsonTypeData {
  test2: string;
  test3?: string;
}
```